# Open differents divs from the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try open differents divs from the same function , my idea it´s change the name of div in each click for generate random divs and call each div

My Script :

```
function load_edit(id,data)
{
var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*9999999);
//alert("ok"+number);
jQuery(".db_edit_float_content").attr("id","db_edit_float_content"+number); 
jQuery("#db_edit_float_content"+number).slideDown(2000);
jQuery(""+id).show(1000).load("edit.php"+data);
}
```

The Code HTML :

```
<div onclick="load_edit("template","source")"></div>

<div id="" class="db_edit_float_content" style="display:none;">
<div id="db_edit_content">
<div id="db_edit_content_header" onclick="close_load_edit();"></div>
<div id="db_edit_content_body">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The script works perfectly , but no get different divs in each click , only shows one and nothing more , i think must works because the name of id change , but no get finally works right

Thank´s for the help , the best regards

Comment: hm, you just jange the attribute of one div. you shoul create nev div instead

Comment: As you can see in the function use this for change the name of id attr("id","db_edit_float_content"+number) , but no works always open one div and no more in each click

Comment: If you want different divs, you should add new ones instead changing one div attribute (you have only one div with class .db_edit_float_content). You could use http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/ to generate divs

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning the same random id to all the divs and then using a id selector which will always fetch only the first element with the said id resulting in returning the first div always.

Instead use a random index value to fetch the div

```
function load_edit(id, data) {
    var $divs = jQuery(".db_edit_float_content");
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length);
    $divs.eq(number).slideDown(2000);
    jQuery("" + id).show(1000).load("edit.php" + data);
}
```

Comment: I try and continue open one div , no differents divs in each click , the idea it´s with each click open new div